# where to apply for long-term student visa to Germany when you are a long term student visa holder in Ireland

Tags: schengen, study

I am Indian,  have currently One-year Resident permit (June 2019-June 2020) in Ireland as a 4-year duration Ph.D. student(June, 2019- June 2023), In this situation, If I accept an offer from Germany, which is also a Ph.D. student position for 3 years, do I need to go back to India and apply for a long-term student visa to go to Germany and start my PhD there, (assuming the fact that I sincerely resign my Ph.D. position here in Ireland)? Or, I can apply for a long-term student visa from the German embassy in Dublin?

PS: I currently possess a one year (Aug 2019- Aug 2020, 90 days at max stay)Schengen Visa from the German embassy in Dublin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consulates and Embassies in general provide service to any legal resident in a given area, and since you are a legal resident of Ireland, the German Consulate and/or Embassy will definitely allow you to apply for a visa.

You can get information about requirements at the German Embassy in Dublin [website](https://dublin.diplo.de/ie-en/service/05-VisaEinreise).